# Which of these two import statements for the MongoDB/golang mgo driver is correct?

Tags: mongodb, go, mgo

Could someone shed some light on the difference between these two import statements for the same mgo (MongoDB/golang) library:

```
gopkg.in/mgo.v2
labix.org/v2/mgo
```

I know you have to pick one or the other, but they both seem to work the same for me. Why are there two and which one should I be using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They are the same package, and there is no canonical import enforced for mgo.

Use the "gopkg.in/mgo.v2", if only because that's what the documentation states.

Comment: Thanks, but I am also hoping to understand why a library might do this. I am relatively new to Go and perhaps this is fairly common.

Comment: @jzapata: The reason is history: Gustavo made mgo and used hosted the project on his labix.org site. He later created the gopkg.in service (which anyone can use), and started using that for versioning the driver. The latter url is not enforced as the canonical import in the code, so either could be used, and they both point to the actual git repo at https://github.com/go-mgo/mgo/tree/v2.